# ROS Answers SE migration: Robot Roll Out

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I maintain our own little robot and have written many packages (demonstrations, messages, simulation, etc.) to work with it.
Just to give you an example of the package for the Gazebo simulator: https://github.com/tik0/amiro_robot
So my intention is now to clean stuff up and to roll out all packages and documentation to the world.
The point is, I am a bit unsure with how and where to start. For now, I (and my fellows) work still very naively in catkin workspaces with all the packages beeing build in-place.

**So the question**: Are there guidelines/how-to/care-about to build install-packages, roll-out documention and all that stuff? Of course, I could just look into other famous packages like [hector-slam](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam) and read through all the REP. But I actually thought more of a red-threat on a *how-to roll out*.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293833/robot-roll-out/) by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 220 on 2018-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It may not be as comprehensive as you're asking for, but the [wiki/Bloom](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom) pages have quite a bit of information about this. The [Full guide for releasing with catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/FullGuideToFirstTimeRelease) page has the same info, but more dense.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) on 2018-06-29**:
That's nice! You can post this as answer!